# Как распознают капчи?

Tags: captcha, curl, php

Я вот знаю парочку способов: это, если простая капча, нарезать на кусочки капчу так, чтобы в каждом кусочке было по символу, после записать md5 хеш каждого символа в массив вместе с самим символом. Массив примерно так выглядеть будет:

```
$cap['c93d3bf7a7c4afe94b64e30c2ce39f4f'] = "2";
```

И дальше уже тогда, когда нужно распознать капчу, надо будет нарезать её на символы и узнать md5 каждого символа, сравнить с массивом и подставить. Но с такой бесполезной капчей сайтов единицы. Поэтому есть более ужасный способ: скачивать все капчи проекта и получать их md5 хеш. Потом уже сравнивать. А значения капчи будут забивать пользователи, которые хотят "подзаработать", им выдаётся картинка, они вводят, в базу записывается проект, с которого капча, md5 капчи и значение. И за введённую капчу им платят копейки. Пример: kolotibablo.com.

**Теперь вопросики:**

Но как на таких сервисах как "КолотиБабло" проверяют, правильно ли ввёл капчу пользователь?
Есть ли ещё способы распознания капчи?
Как работают сервисы типа antigate.com?
Где можно попрактиковаться в сURL, а то везде сильные защиты, никак не найду подходящего полигона, и в каких целях, кроме как отправка форм, используется данная библиотека?

Comment: скачать все "капчи" проекта?))) может я не понял чего но насколько я знаю на более менее крупных сайтах они рандомно генерируются...
**(без пробелов вводите, это просто чтобы неиндексировалось, модераторы возьмите в тег noindex)** *Facepalm*

Comment: Они практически везде генерируются рандомно, я про это и говорю, вы посмотрите сначала указанный сервис где нужно вводить капчи за деньги, а рендомность не гарантирует случаев без повторений, к примеру echo rand(1,10) - попробуйте обновить страничку 11 раз как минимум 1 повтрение будет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Ломаем капчу](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/infosecurity/63854/)
2. [Ломаем каптчу Яндекса](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/artificial_intelligence/64535/)

Comment: Спасибо, очень интересные статеечки)))

Answer (score 1):

Antigate работает по одной системе. Сидят люди, им приходит ваша капча, они её распознают, и высылают вам ответ. Поэтому сервис Antigate распознает от 10 до 20 секунд. Никакого кода, только рабочие руки :)

Comment: Хах, забавно)) Да это обезьянья работа)

Answer (score 1):

http://pixodrom.com (бывший http://anti-captcha.net) работает как антигейт:
загружаешь им капчу через API, они её переправляют своим работникам, те распознают и отправляют ответ обратно в систему. По ID капчи забираем ответ на свою капчу.

Answer (score 0):

Простите, но если капча не элементарная, её ни одна система даже распознавания образов не распознает.